# Moving MySQL database to another server

Tags: mysql

I have a website build using [Q2A engine](http://question2answer.org/)

Since I have about 600 active users there, I'm trying to create a copy of it on a second server for test purposes only.

I've copied all the files and exported the website (about 28MB raw SQL / 8MB .gz file), but when I'm trying to import it on a new server I get the error:

```
SELECT USER(
);



MySQL returned error:  
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

What could go wrong?

I've tried several methods: importing raw sql file, gz file, importing on clean database, import on top of installed fresh copy of q2a etc... always the same error.

Comment: Thanks for updating with a solution - please add it below as an answer and check it when you can so the question can be considered closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I managed to get it work. I chopped the sql export and exported separately: the structure (1 file) and the data up to 5 tables at a time.

Importing the data on a new server in such pieces returned no error.

Answer (score 0):

First perform:

`Mysqldump --all-databases > all.sql`

Then do:

`mysql < all.sql`

Answer (score 0):

For complete DB backup, make sure that all store procedures and functions are exported with SQL dump or  export.

Use the following command to backup and restore database routines.

Step 1:

```
mysqldump -u mysql_user   -p   --no-create-db --no-create-info --no-data --routines     
source_db_name  >  dump.sql
```

Step 2. Restore dump on target database:

```
mysql  -u  mysql_user -p user_password      
target_DB_name  < dump.sql
```